# Example of when $E^{H} \neq E^{\text{Aut}(E/E^H)}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, examples-counterexamples, automorphism-group

Let $E/F$ be a field extension of $F$, and let $H \leq \text{Aut}(E/F)$ be a subgroup of the automorphisms of $E$ fixing $F$. If $H$ is finite, then it is well-known that $H = \text{Aut}(E/E^H)$ and so $E^{H} = E^{\text{Aut}(E/E^H)}$, where $E^H$ is the fixed field of $H$.

Therefore, to find an example where equality does not hold, we necessarily require $H$ to be infinite. So I tried looking at $E = \mathbb{R}(x)$ and $F = \mathbb{R}$, which gives
\begin{align}
\text{Aut}(\mathbb{R}(x)/\mathbb{R}) \cong GL_2(\mathbb{R})\bigg/\begin{pmatrix}\lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
with $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^\times$. An automorphism can be constructed by considering $g = \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix} \in GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ and defining a map $\phi: GL_2(\mathbb{R}) \to \text{Aut}(\mathbb{R}(x)/\mathbb{R}) $ by $g \mapsto \phi(g)$ where, for $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}(x)$, we have
\begin{align}
\phi(g)(f) = f\left(\frac{ax + c}{bx + d}\right).
\end{align}
The only problem is that I don't know how to find the fixed field. Say if I took $H = SO_2(\mathbb{R})\bigg/\begin{pmatrix}\lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda\end{pmatrix} < \text{Aut}(\mathbb{R}(x)/\mathbb{R})$, then, to obtain the fixed field $\mathbb{R}(x)^H$, I would require all rational functions $f$ satisfying
\begin{align}
f\left(\frac{x\cos\theta  + \sin\theta}{-x\sin\theta  + \cos\theta}\right) = f(x).
\end{align}
How should I proceed from here, or, is there an easier example I can examine?

Comment: You cannot have $E^H\neq E^{Aut(E/E^H)}$. Note that $H\leq Aut(E/E^H)$ always holds, and it implies $E^{Aut(E/E^H)}\leq E^H$. On the other hand,  $E^H\leq E^{Aut(E/E^H)}$ is straight-forward: if $x\in E^H$ and $g\in Aut(E/E^H)$ then obviously $g(x)=x$, hence $x\in E^{Aut(E/E^H)}$. Maybe you want to ask for an example that $H\neq Aut(E/E^H)$? Or that $E^{Aut(E/L)}\neq L$ for an intermediate field $L$?

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for.  I could show myself that $E^H \subset E^{\text{Aut}(E/E^H)}$ in the way you said, but I missed $H \leq \text{Aut}(E/E^H)$.